# Count all words in a sentence separated by spaces

Tags: python

in Python I want an user to type a sentence using the Input argument.

```
zin = input("Typ een zinnetje: ")
```

In a function I want to count all words (everything separated by spaces.) 
how do I do this?

this is what I have so far.

```
zin = input("Typ een zinnetje: ")
def gemiddelde():
    aantal = zin.count(zin)
    return aantal

print (gemiddelde())
```

This prints 1 no matter what.

Comment: How many times does a string contain itself? **Once**. `zin.count(zin)`  is obviously not what you should be doing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`split` will break string by space and `len` will return length:

```
zin = input("Typ een zinnetje: ")
def gemiddelde():
    aantal = len(zin.split())
    return aantal

print (gemiddelde())
```

Answer (score 4):

you need to split sentence by space and then use `len`

```
zin = raw_input("Typ een zinnetje: ")
def gemiddelde():
    aantal = len(zin.split(' '))
    return aantal

print (gemiddelde())
```

Answer (score 1):

```
zin = input("Typ een zinnetje: ")
def gemiddelde():
        aantal = zin.split(" ")
        return aantal.__len__()

print (gemiddelde())
```

Comment: gives an error AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'length'

Comment: lol @juanpa.arrivillaga you are correct...actually I'm doing coding in Java from today morning :P

Comment: @GauravSharma you should use `len`, don't use "dunder" methods directly, they are designed to be hooks into things like `len` or `str` or even operators like `+`, i.e. `__add__`

Answer (score 0):

Further to the answers before me, split will split the string on every occurrence of a space meaning that it may read more words if there are things like double spaces or leading/trailing spaces. It may be worth doing some quick checks to make sure what you get is actually the number of words.

```
zin = input("Typ een zinnetje: ")

def gemiddelde():
    aantal = zin.split(" ")
    num = sum(len(x) > 0 for x in aantal)
    return num

print (gemiddelde())
```

Comment: If you use `s.split()` (i.e. with no argument), this is never an issue.

Comment: But that only works for spaces.  If you have any other separator character it can be an issue.  For user input, extraneous spaces are probably unintentional.  In other cases (say a database export) multiple spaces may indicate null columns. @Brandon.Hadfield is correct though that it could be an issue.

Comment: @WombatPM. Nope - `s.split()` works for all whitespace characters, and always does the right thing. There is never any need to check for empty strings in the output.

Comment: @ekhumoro Respectfully disagree.  I may WANT the empty columns.  Consider ```>>> s = "1\t2\t3\t\t5\n"
>>> s.split('\t')
['1', '2', '3', '', '5\n']
>>> s.split()
['1', '2', '3', '5']```  My point was that context matters and Brandon was correct to raise the issue

Comment: @WombatPM. It's not a matter of opinion. The above answer states that "split will split the string on every occurrence of a space meaning that it may read more words if there are things like double spaces or leading/trailing spaces". But that is only true if an argument is specified - without one, all whitespace issues are completely eliminated. Note that the accepted answer correctly uses `len(zin.split()))`. This is guaranteed to give the right result, no matter what input is received. It would be just plain wrong to include empty strings, since the OP wants to *count all words*.

Answer (score 0):

In a single line,

```
def count_words(s):
    return len(s.split())
```

The `split()` function will split the `string s` into `list of words`, where the delimiter for the split is `whitespace`. The `len()` will return the number of elements that were obtained when the string was split.

Answer (score 0):

```
zin = input("Typ een zinnetje: ")

def gemiddelde(s):
    return len(s.split(' '))

print (gemiddelde(zin))
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.